# How to pay IRS CP14H

Tags: united-states, irs, online-payment

I received a Notice CP14H from the IRS to pay a small amount of owed money. I want to do this online instead of mailing a check or money order.
I went to irs.gov/payments and looked at my options, but not finding anything that specifies CP14H.

If I want to Direct Pay on the IRS site, I'm given the option to Apply Payment to:

- 1040, 1040A, 1040EZ
- 1040ES
- 1040X
- 5329
- Civil Penalty
- Health Care (Form 1040)

But of course I can't direct pay today, it's Saturday and their payment computer has the day off...

And if use one of the credit card services, like PayUSATax.com or OfficialPayments.com, there are even more options (not to mention an additional fee).

Which option do I choose to apply this payment?

Thanks,
Dave K.

Comment: I suspect CP in CP14H stands for Civil Penalty...

Comment: That's what i was wondering too, but at the same time, the penalty is from my wife not having health coverage for a couple months. Neither of the two other sites I listed have the Civil Penalty Option, but there is a "Form 1040 Health Care: Individual Responsibility Notice Payment" (along with other Health Care options) on one of the sites, so I don't know what to check off.

Comment: Why not just mail a check?

Comment: it's due monday.

Comment: With IRS it is usually by postmark, so I wouldn't worry too much about it

Comment: @littleadv CP stands for Computer Paragraph, which means a notice 'systemically' generated (IRS jargon for automated) using prewritten text -- what other people call a 'form letter'. Some of these involve penalties but nowhere near all; see https://www.irs.gov/individuals/irs-notice-or-letter-for-individual-filers (click View All) and the similar page ending business-filers . And even though this is really a penalty, the law (PPACA) is very careful NOT to call it that, and so is the IRS. Thus=>DaveK: I believe the 1040 Health Care 'Responsibility Payment' is indeed the one you want. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

CP14h Shared Responsibility payments for Health Care should be paid online at IRS.gov/payments using the Health Care - Form 1040 selection for the appropriate tax year. A normal CP14 is paid online using the "Tax Return or Notice (1040)" selection.